# How to bind owned domain name from aws route 53 to a jelastic URL

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, jelastic

I have bought a domain called derbyware.com from Amazon AWS Route 53, and until now I have ben
using it for hosting a static website hosted on AWS S3.
Now I have deployed a Java EE 7 application on Jelastic. I need to make the domain derbyware.com
to point to the Jelastic 'ugly' "http://node147934-env-7029269.phx.enscaled.us" URL for my Java EE application.
I have readed Jelastic documentation for Custom Domain Names, and I learned how to make 
the binding from Jelastic to derbyware.com, but I don't how to use Route 53 to redirect to the 
Jelastic URL.
Can You please help me set Route 53 to redirect to the new URL (instruction 1)

Jelastic Instructions:
1. Log in to your domain registrar and add canonical name (CNAME) for the preliminary 
bought external domain so it points to your Jelastic environment URL, e.g.:
www.myexternaldomain.com CNAME env_name.{hoster_domain}

This Instruction I do know how to do it:
3. Within the automatically selected Custom domains menu tab, use the Domain binding 
section to specify your domain name (e.g. www.myexternaldomain.com) and Bind it with 
the corresponding button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Route 53 you need to "Create Record Set" with:

- Name: "www" (.derbyware.com)
- Type: "CNAME - Canonical Name"
- Alias: "No"
- Value: "env-7029269.phx.us.enscaled.us"

*(without quotes)*

On the Jelastic side, it looks like you already have everything configured properly for www.derbyware.com

Note: for derbyware.com (no www) you cannot use a CNAME. The recommended approach is to add a public IP - available on paid accounts - and then point the bare domain by A record directly to your externally facing node.

Comment: thank you very much, now www.derbyware.com work correctly, but derbyware.com (without www) does not. Can you please elaborate on that. I need it to work as well too

Comment: I see that you got this working, but just in case it helps others: you need to add a public IP to the external node (e.g. in this case it was an nginx load balancer node), and then add an A record pointing the bare domain (derbyware.com) to the assigned public IP.

Comment: now I fixed the second issue too, now derbyware.com also works. (using Layshift support)